# Custom Event Listener for Keycloak of version 18.0.0

Tags: java, windows, keycloak, event-listener, keycloak-services

I am trying to create an event listener for Keycloak:
[Project structure and META-INF.services.org.keycloak.events.EventListenerProviderFactory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RuB6.png)

CustomEventListenerProviderFactory:

```
public class CustomEventListenerProviderFactory implements EventListenerProviderFactory {

    private static final String LISTENER_ID = "event-listener-extension";

    @Override
    public EventListenerProvider create(KeycloakSession session) {
        return new CustomEventListenerProvider();
    }

    @Override
    public void init(Config.Scope scope) {

    }

    @Override
    public void postInit(KeycloakSessionFactory keycloakSessionFactory) {

    }

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return LISTENER_ID;
    }

}
```

CustomEventListenerProvider:

```
@Slf4j
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CustomEventListenerProvider implements EventListenerProvider {

    @Override
    public void onEvent(Event event) {
      log.info("Caught event {}", EventUtils.toString(event));
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(AdminEvent adminEvent, boolean b) {
        log.info("Caught admin event {}", EventUtils.toString(adminEvent));

        List<CustomAdminEvent> events = new LinkedList<>();
        events.add(new PasswordResetEvent(adminEvent));

        events.stream().filter(CustomAdminEvent::isValid).forEach(CustomAdminEvent::process);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }
}
```

But when I run `mvn clean package` and copy [target folder after mvn commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNBSL.png) the jar file into the [path to deployment folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7DWh.png) and then run the command to start Keycloak in cmd

```
kc.bat start-dev --http-port 8082
```

No custom events are displayed.

[Events in Keycloak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9N6TB.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNvYf.png)

Just put the provider files in the providers folder.
Put the theme files in the theme folder.
No more, no less.
Also read READMNE.md in those folders....

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).