# Keycloak 19.0 - Send Welcome User email to registered user

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, user-registration, keycloak-rest-api

I want to send an email to the registered user once the admin creates a new user saying that " the user successfully registered with the xyz email id.. " Is there any option to achieve this in keycloak 19.03 or above ?

Or Is it an out of box option in keycloak ?

Currently on initial login attempt, the newly created users can opt for forgot password and they will get a password reset link, through which them can login and verify their email. But welcome mail is possible ?

Any help is greatly appreciated !!

Answer (score 1):

This is not an out of the box feature from Keycloak, but can be easily extended.
**Step 1:** Update your realm to record the events, show in below image.
[image]

**Step 2:** Extend the Event listener API from keycloak. You can find official guide here -> https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_events

Listen to user registration events and send appropriate emails.

Comment: this events settings will save events to keyloak db right ....how can the api be extended to send emails.. i saw the email.ftl template inside the themes folder in previous keycloak documentation,. for the  keycloak19th version  the themes folder seems empty, some restructuring has been applied it seems..  i am using react.js and is it possible to do so ? @umakanth

Comment: Yes, the events are saved in the db, and actually the email templates come later in your solution process, but first you need to implement the event listener api. Take look at this SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72181321/custom-event-listener-for-keycloak-of-version-18-0-0 it will give you some idea where to start. You will finally be creating a custom jar which you will be adding in keycloak providers folder.

Comment: Thank you , i will check and update here.. hope the same can be achieved in react also instead of java@ umakanth

Comment: Well I am not very sure if you can do it in react, this very java dependent. Maybe someone in the community has tried and might respond with the possibility, but from where I stand you need java for implementing the SPI.

Comment: @A.M If this has answered your question you can close this by accepting the answer or up-voting if you have found it useful.

Comment: The approach is okay but i didnt get a clear solution whether it can be done in react and how to do in react.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to use React to handle the emailing process. React is only used for formatting webpages (or emails), but you will need to write a Java class and install it in Keycloak in order to trigger the process of sending the email in the first place.

If you don't want to write Java, another option is to use an existing plugin to notify you of new users. We are using a RabbitMQ event listener (https://github.com/aznamier/keycloak-event-listener-rabbitmq) to send us messages when a new user is added. You will still need to write some server-side code and host it somewhere (you can use Ruby, PHP, whatever you like) to listen for those messages and trigger sending an email.